# post product data if quantity more than zero

Tags: php

how to send data (product_id, quantity) only of those products which the quantity will be marked more than 0?

I want to do category page like this

[image: example]

Comment: Form always sent all data, put simple condition into your PHP script and check if qty > 0.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: until I get to send data of only one product. I added a button to each product. oh why I myself had not thought of? Now I will try to do for your advice, panther.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['product'] ) ) {

    foreach ( $_POST['product'] as $product ) {
        if ($product['q']>0) {
            add_to_cart( $product['id'], $product['q'] )
        } 
    }
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">

    <input type="number" name="product[0][q]" value="0"/><input type="hidden" name="product[0][id]" value="11"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="product[1][q]" value="0"/><input type="hidden" name="product[1][id]" value="12"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="product[2][q]" value="0"/><input type="hidden" name="product[2][id]" value="13"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="product[3][q]" value="0"/><input type="hidden" name="product[3][id]" value="14"/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="send">

</form>
```